# How to cast Generic parameters from another generic class argument?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, generic-list

I would like to cast Object T to T2 when a specific type of T2 is passed. T2 is a class from interface T, so there can be multiple implementations of T2. 
As far as casting, it's happening properly. But I am unable to access the functions of the typecasted function. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
protected <T, T2> SortedMap<Integer, T2> noNameFunction(List<T> things, T2 ts) {
    SortedMap<Integer, Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap <> (  );
    for (T t: things) {
        T2 as = ( (T2) ts );
        sortedMap.put ( as.getSequence(), as.getFunctionsFromCastedIbjectA() );
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Am I wrong conceptually somewhere? 
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using `instaceof`?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601132/instanceof-keyword-usage

Comment: where are you using your t variable? seems like never used

Comment: When using generics you should not cast anything. Youre handling typesafety via generics

Comment: What is `getFunctionsFromCastedIbjectA()`? Is it a method from a subtype of generic type `T`? And what's the actual type of `T`? Is it `Object` or an interface? If it's an interface, then you shouldn't be using a generic type for it. Just use the type of the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, you cannot invoke any method from `as` that the compiler is not able to determine at compilation time based on the constraints you impose on `T2`.

In your question `T2` could be anything extending `Object` so you can only call methods declared therein like `toString`, `hashCode` etc... pretty useless.

If for whatever reason you can narrow down the `T2` type (thus `T`) to extend a more concrete class or interface then you would gain access to its member methods, For example imagine that T, thus T2, is guaranteed to be `Number` so you could call `intValue`.

That probably would solve you problems with `T` methods such as `getSequence` as I presume that in fact `T` is bounded in your code to be some class that defines the `getSequence` method. Let's say that it called `SequenceContainer`.

```
protected <T extends SequenceContainer, T2 extends T>  SortedMap<Integer, T2> noNameFunction(List<T> things, T2 ts) {
    SortedMap<Integer, Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap <> (  );
    for (T t: things) {
        T2 as = ( (T2) t ); 
        sortedMap.put ( as.getSequence(), as.t2OwnMethod() ); // fail to compile, due to the call to t2OwnMethod.
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

The full solution is to use a lambda that allows the caller to provide the T2 code that needs to be invoked inside the method.

```
protected <T extends SequenceContainer, T2 extends T, X>  SortedMap<Integer, X> noNameFunction(List<T> things, T2 ts, Function<T2, X> valueFunction) {
    SortedMap<Integer, Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap <> (  );
    for (T t: things) {
        T2 as = ( (T2) t ); 
        sortedMap.put ( as.getSequence(), valueFunction.apply(as)); // fail to compile, due to the call to t2OwnMethod.
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Notice that I have taken this opportunity to generalize the value of the returned sorted-map to a third type `X`... this could be simply `T2` and will be solved seamlessly at compilation time depending what lambda you provide. Now the way you would invoke this signature assuming that `t2OwnMethod` returns ... a String say, is:

```
List<? extends SequenceContainer> scs = ...;
SpecialSequenceContainer exampleSSC = ...; /// SpecialSequenceContainer extends 
SortedMap<Integer, String> option1 = noNameFunction(scs, exampleSSC, ssc -> ssc.t2OwnMethod());
// or 
SortedMap<Integer, String> option2 = noNameFunction(scs, exampleSSC, 
    SpecialSequenceContainer::t2OwnMethod);
```

Now, notice that the second parameter (exampleSSC) is quite useless... so you could simply omit it.

We can go even further here and use Java streams to do all the work in the question code:

```
final SortedMap<Integer, String> result = myScs.stream()
     .map(t -> (SpecialSequenceContainer) t)
     .collect(SequenceContainer::getSequence, 
              SpecialSequenceContainer::t2OwnMethod, 
              (s1, s2) -> s1, 
              TreeMap::new);
```

Notice that `(s1, s2) -> s1` lambda would only be invoked if there are key collisions, perhaps that would never be the case but you need to provide the value merging function regardless.

Comment: I like your approach, upvoted! I'd only have a couple of comments... 1) Having the generic type `T` seems pointless. Just use the type of the interface, in your case this would be `SequenceContainer`. Also make the list be of type `List<? extends SequenceContainer>` 2) Besides the function to extract the values, I'd also use a function to extract the keys, so the method would be as generic as possible. With streams, there's no need for the method...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner, yes ```List<? extends SequenceContainer>``` is more correct... arguably there is a chance that it the real code he can go further and enclose this code into another method that would define ```T2``` as a type-parameter and the this could be rewritten as ```List<T2>``` (and the map or cast would go away) ... up to the level where the code would be aware of what T2 actually is. Yes, you right ```T``` is rather pointless at this point (no punt intended); there is a few more things that can be improved from the original code, I've just pointed out a couple.